# Borderlands second playthrough with beginner co-op players

Tags: borderlands

In Borderlands 1, if I were to play through the game once alone and start playthrough 2 but with friends (that just got the game), would it be easier for them to level up or would the difficulty be to much at the beginning and not be so fun playing?

Comment: Are you allowed to accomplish missions in playthrough 2 if you've never played playthrough 1?

Comment: My personal suggestion would be for you to start a new character along with them - you'd be able to help lead them through the areas you know well, and tell them strategies for difficult bosses, but you wouldn't be an overpowered tank who's having to do the majority of the work.

Comment: Just start a new character to play through playthrough 1 with your friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think only your friends could say what's fun for them, but odds are they wouldn't enjoy it much. Essentially they'd have to hide behind you and let you kill everything, since their weapons wouldn't be able to do much damage. They'd level up pretty quickly, but it'd still take quite a while before they got to the point of being able to truly join in fights.

Comment: That is how it was in Diablo, i was basically just a fly to the enemies. I wasn't sure how well Borderlands would scale with level differences.